# How to compare Some Column with it self depending on Group by result?

Tags: sql

I have one table where I have a translation field. The table has countryID depending on that we can get the Translated text for some English word for different language. now I want to compare the English Word with another language word for the same word. whether there are extra spaces or special char in other language Translated Text.

[Image One : Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlChf.png)

[Image Two : Different translation for the same word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaBLG.png)

Comment: Please review [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/243373) on why it is a bad idea to post a question with images for your table structure.

Comment: need urgent help .. images for reference for person who can understand.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is something like this:

```
select 
  t1.fieldName,
  t1.translatedText,
  t2.translatedText
  case 
    when t1.translatedText = t2.translatedText then 'equal'
    else 'not equal'
    end isEqual
from myTable t1,myTable t2
where t1.CultureName = 'en-US'
and   t2.CultureName = 'ru-RU'
and   t1.fieldName = t2.fieldName
```